# C++ Segmentation fault with push_back on list but not on vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

We are doing a hashtable with chaining example for class.  Using the STL I defined the hashtable as `std::vector<std::list< Pair > > mTable`.  Unfortunately, when I call push_back on mTable[index] I get a seg fault.  The error does NOT exist if I define mTable to be `std::vector<std::vector< Pair > > mTable.`
Am I using list incorrectly?  Here is the code:

```
template<class K, class V>
class HashTable {
    private:
        class Pair {
            public:
                K mKey;
                V mVal;
        };
        std::vector<std::list<Pair> > mTable;
...
};

...

template<class K, class V>
HashTable<K, V>::HashTable(const int size) {
    mTable.reserve(size);
}

template<class K, class V>
bool HashTable<K, V>::insert(const K &key, const V &val) {
    int size = mTable.capacity(); // Gets how many elements can be stored in the array/vector.
    int index = hashcode(key); // convert the key to an integer.
    index %= size; // Size down the 'size' variable so it index into the array/vector.
    Pair toInsert;
    toInsert.mKey = key;
    toInsert.mVal = val;
    std::cout << mTable[index].size() << "\n"; // works fine.
    mTable[index].push_back(toInsert); // (SEG FAULT) Adds value to the hash table
}
```

Comment: `mTable.capacity()` and `mTable.size()` do not necessarily return the same values. Also what do you see are the values of `index` and `mTable.size()` when you debug the code?

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you don't just use `std::pair` instead of rolling your own?

Comment: You never create the vector containing your table, you only reserve space for it.

Comment: You should first do mTable.push_back(list) to have the std::list object inserted into std::vector, later can do mTable[index].push_back(toInsert)

Comment: UnholySheep: Yes, but I need the capacity to know the legal range for the vector.  A better variable name might be availableSpace or something.


Steve: No, I'll use pair in the future, thanks.


Johan: I don't understand, but creating the class, it should implicitly create the vector since I'm not using a pointer...


webbi: I don't understand.  When I do the .reserve, it creates 100 double links lists.  I can confirm this, but when I try mTable[0].size() I get 0, not a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HashTable<K, V>::HashTable(const int size):mTable(size,std::list<Pair>){
}
```

Comment: This essentially works.  Although, I had to remove the second parameter:  HashTable<K, V>::HashTable(const int size):mTable(size)  I also removed the reserved function call.  Although, two questions, why did the reserve function call not work?  Also, why did vector not have this issue.  Thanks!